# how to import data from H2 database to elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, h2

I am trying to search data from H2 database using elasticsearch. elasticsearch work fine in my project.I added elasticsearch externally.when i add data using constructor it adds to elasticsearch.but if try to add data from H2 database to elasticsearch I am getting this error.
-Error creating bean with name 'itemMigrator' defined in file.
-Error creating bean with name 'userJpaRepository': Invocation of init method failed;
-No property findAll found for type User!

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.6.RELEASE

elasticsearch version-5.6.12

I am following this example https://www.hameister.org/SpringBootElasticsearch.html

http://techprimers.com/spring-data-elastic-search-example-3-using-spring-jpa/

**User.java**

```
    @Entity
@Document(indexName = "user", type = "user", shards = 1)
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
```

**SearchQueryBuilder.java**

```
@Component
    public class SearchQueryBuilder {

         private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

            @Autowired
            public SearchQueryBuilder(ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate) {
                this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
            }

        public List<User> getAll(String text) {

            QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .should(
                            QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(text)
                                    .lenient(true)
                                    .field("firstName")
                                    .field("role")
                    ).should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + text + "*")
                            .lenient(true)
                            .field("firstName")
                            .field("role"));

            NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(query)
                    .build();

            List<User> userses = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(build, User.class);

            return userses;
        }
    }
```

**ItemMigrator.java**

```
@Autowired
    ElasticsearchOperations operations;
    @Autowired
    UsersRepository UsersRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserJpaRepository jpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ItemMigrator(UserJpaRepository jpaRepository, ElasticsearchTemplate operations, UsersRepository UsersRepository) {
        this.jpaRepository = jpaRepository;
        this.operations = operations;
        this.UsersRepository = UsersRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void loadAll() {
        Iterable<User> items = jpaRepository.findAll();
        operations.putMapping(User.class);
        UsersRepository.saveAll(items);
    }

}
```

**UserJpaRepository.java**

```
    public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

**UsersRepository.java**

```
public interface UsersRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Long>{
        List<User> findByFirstName(String text);
        List<User> findByRole(String text);
```

**ManualSearchResource.java**

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/manual/search")
public class ManualSearchResource {

     @Autowired
        private SearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder;

        @GetMapping(value = "/{text}")
        public List<User> getAll(@PathVariable final String text) {
            return searchQueryBuilder.getAll(text);
        }
}
```

**Config.java**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.kzn.shoppingbackend" })
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                 .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                    .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
         return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

This is my stacktrace https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxf2a3m961dx7a7/elastic_error.txt?dl=0

Is it correct to add both @Entity and @Document is same class?Please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: @Patrick  actually i try that but I am getting same error thats why i confuse thats correct way or not.

Comment: @Patrick  i will edit code as you said

Comment: The example you followed says it could be done to use both. Have you also used the same configuration for `ElasticConfiguration ` as provided? Can you show your Config, please

Comment: @Patrick i added config file.

Comment: No i added configuration as shown on this page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.6/transport-client.html

Comment: @Patrick I added stacktrace link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxf2a3m961dx7a7/elastic_error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Have you seen that in the example: _t should be noted that with Spring Boot 1.5 the two repositories can not be in the same package, otherwise the component scan will not work. This issue should be resolved with Spring Boot 2.0._ Can you check that

Comment: but i am using spring boot 2.0.6 and I added both repositories inside different packages.

Comment: if you have the repositories in different packages why the config is not different. You have both configurations in the same package `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.kzn.shoppingbackend" })`

Comment: I changed @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend.jpa")
 @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend.repository") but getting same error.

Comment: @Patrick I used logstash to import data to elasticsearch and changed db from h2 to mysql. that solved my problem.